# Zeropad numbering in Batch File (pushd)

Tags: batch-file

How could I get zeros padding like "file0001.jpg"?

```powershell
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set Num=1

for /r %%i in (*.jpg) do (
    ren "%%i" "file!Num!.jpg"
    set /a Num+=1
)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can format number to get the leading `0`s.

```
set j=0000%%num
```

Comment: Sure, but what if the number is 10 and they only need two digits?

Comment: And you are not using the percent symbols correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
set Num=1000000

for /r %%i in (*.jpg) do (
    ren "%%i" "file!Num:~-4!.jpg"
```

The numbers then start from 1000000, and the part of the number inserted into the filename is the last 4 characters (so `0000`, `0001`, etc.)

See `set /?` from the prompt for documentation.